Emission lines from atom (for example, neon)
Atomic emission lines are very useful for a variety of purposes, especially in spectroscopy. I wonder, if the pressure of the  pressure of the carrier gas has any effect on the emission characteristics.
For example, the standard lamps based on mercury and neon would have some carrier gas as well in the chamber, usually argon/helium. One such case is referenced to on wikipedia about the appearance of additional lines (resulting in different overall observed color). Wiki page on neon lamp
My question is about the original line by neon and whether it would be perturbed ?
Thank you.

The light emitted by a gas discharge lamp depends on pressure:

The color of the light produced depends on the emission spectra of the atoms making up the gas, as well as the pressure of the gas, current density, and other variables. Gas discharge lamps can produce a wide range of colors. Some lamps produce ultraviolet radiation which is converted to visible light by a fluorescent coating on the inside of the lamp's glass surface. The fluorescent lamp is perhaps the best known gas-discharge lamp.

(the quoted Wikipedia article also has sections on low-pressure and high-pressure lamps.)
Returning to the question:

My question is about the original line by neon and whether it would be perturbed ?

Neon or any other atom has multiple lines, between all possible pairs of levels, although the line between the first excited state and the ground state is usually the most manifest. The different colors in the lamp thus result not from modification of the lines, but from exciting the atoms to higher energy states, and thus observing more of the transition lines inherent to the species of atom in question.
Actually modifying the atomic lines would require bringing atoms together to distances compared to their size - high-density plasma conditions which are not realized in practice on earth (except for some high-notch experiments.)
Here is an appropriate image (after a brief google search) that compares a spectrum of a neon lamp to the spectrum lines of Neon (image source):

You may be also interested to read about a Helium-Neon laser.

The line positions can change to some extent due to pressure. Maybe some broadening as well. Right  ?

@mangoJam broadening - yes, definitely collisional broadening, which is affected by density. Changing line positions requires actual interaction between atoms, which requires them to be close - hence my remark about a high-density plasma. In He-Ne laser the atomic collision are responsible for transferring energy from He to Ne, and exciting specific energy line.

To add another example to Roger V.'s answer
Low pressure sodium lamps produce a spectrally clean, brilliant orange/yellow glow discharge which comes from the so-called "d line" in the emission spectrum. Only the d line gets excited because the electrical current which is trickled through the sodium vapor to excite it is small.
High-pressure sodium lamps produce a more complex spectrum which is closer to white because they run at much higher excitation power which brings more possible transitions into play. They run a lot hotter and are operating at higher pressure than the low-pressure lamps so the clear capsule containing the hot vapor has to be thicker and stronger in this case.
